# An increasing smooth map $f:(0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$ which does not extend to any smooth function on a larger domain

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Although I'm not sure it's related, I have found a smooth map $f:(0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$ which does not extend to any continuous function on a larger domain, namely $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\big{(}\frac{1}{x(x-1)}\big{)}$. This behaves like $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$, and all other adjustments are made to ensure the image is contained in $(0,1)$.

Now I'm after a function as in the question - the 'increasing' restriction means I can't use any tricks like $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as above. I imagine there exists a continuous extension of such map, even if there is not a smooth one. Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: If you integrated $\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|$, you'd get an increasing function, whose derivative could not be extended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f: (0,1) \to (0,1)$ is smooth and does not extend continuously to $[0,1]$ (because it does not have limits as $x \to 0+$ or $1-$), then
$$g(x) = \dfrac{\int_0^x f(t)\; dt}{\int_0^1 f(t)\; dt}$$
is smooth and increasing and does not extend to a $C^1$ function on a larger domain.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is increasing, the limits as $x\to0^+$. and as $x\to1^-$ both  exist. $f(x)=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x}+1)/2$ satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw this in: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin (2x-1).$

Comment: It might be valuable if you demonstrate the technique of proving it cannot be extended.